# What properties of MOSFET amplifiers made it so popular?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, amplifier

It seems to me that any circuit where the output voltage varies faster than the input voltage can be used to create an amplifier (for example a diode). We can bias the input voltage and use small signals to deal with nonlinearity to exploit this circuit for amplification.

Why then, was the MOSFET special as an amplifier? Was it cheapest to build, simplest, etc.?

Comment: Please edit your question to explain how you can amplify using a diode. It may affect the answers.

Comment: We usually don't call a device or circuit an amplifier unless it is able to deliver more power to the output than was applied at the input. For example, transformers can output higher voltage (at lower current) or higher current (at lower voltage) than is applied at the input, but we usually don't say they are amplifiers.

Comment: Is the MOSFET indeed "special" as an amplifier?  Do MOSFETs process more analog signals than BJTs do?  Or are you lumping digital circuits into the category of "amplifiers"?

Comment: Adding to Tim's comment - MOSFETs are actually not very popular as linear amplifiers.

Comment: "*any circuit where the output voltage varies faster than the input voltage*" I know what you are trying to say, but the wording could be more clear. Perhaps "*any circuit where the rate of change of the output is higher than the rate of change of the input*"?

Comment: The facetious answer might be because they are highly successful in digital circuits, ironically. So they try to use them in even more places because they are used everywhere else.

Comment: A diode is a passive element and behaves like a resistor in small signal regime, you cannot use it as an amplifier. To achieve power gain you need active element like MOSFET or BJT.

Answer (score 0):

Older power MOSFETS were temperature stable and did not self-destruct.

Newer power MOSFETS (this is according to the automobile industry and to NASA)
can self-destruct.

Thus your question may need to reflect the generation of FET.